# Reactjs y laravel 10 me da error al iniciar sesion

Tags: laravel, reactjs

Estoy haciendo este proyecto con Reactjs de Front y la app de Laravel 10, pero me sale este error de pantalla al darle iniciar sesión

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:539:27

Alguien sabrá como podría arreglarlo?

Comment: En algun lugar estas tratando de acceder a la propiedad status de algo que no está definido.... agrega un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de tu código para que podamos ayudarte.